# Python Fibonacci using

Tags: python

Good day, I want to write a python code to recursively calculate the entries of the Fibonacci sequence using a function. This function should take in as input an integer number which should denote the limit after which the recursion should stop.

This is what I have:

```
def fib2(n: int) -> int: 
    if n<2: 
        return n
    return fib2(n - 2) + fib2(n - 1) # recursive case
```

If I call this function, say fib(4) I only get '4' returned, whereas I expect a set of calls, namely the recursion calls. Where is the mistake?

Edit: Thanks for the tips. I'm just at the beginning of learning Python and realized after the fact that the code indeed worked out. So I'm getting the right output. The reason I was confused was that I was expecting to obtain the whole series of outputs leading to the final expression. Now I know that this would be possible using a for-loop, for example.

Comment: Aside from the final `return` not being indented properly, this looks fine. (And with the incorrect indentation, you should be getting a syntax error for using `return` outside a function.)

Comment: Indenting the final return properly, I get `fib2(4) == 3`, which is at least reasonable (without quibbling over how to index the numbers).

Comment: "I only get 4 returned" — Well the other returns were used in order to calculate the 4, so the recursion worked. I'm not sure what you were expecting if not that. Are you confusing returning with printing, perhaps?

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Most of all, please explain *exactly* what you don't understand from the output you get when you trace this code. Include that trace in your MRE.  Your post shows no effort to diagnose the problem.  Since this is solved in *myriad* places on the Internet, and you haven't included any of that research, your post is not yet ready for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think f(1) = 0 so you need to make it

```
def fib2(n: int) -> int: 
    if n==1: 
        return 0
    elif n==2:
        return 1
return fib2(n - 2) + fib2(n - 1) # recursive case
```

I think you have a mistake in actually implementing the Fibonacci algorithm.

Comment: It depends on whether you want the indices to start with 0 or 1. In neither case should `f(4)` return 4, as claimed. You also haven't fixed the more glaring issue of the `return`-outside-a-function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is in implementing the Fibonacci algorithm.

> The Fibonacci sequence: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21

According to Wikipedia [Fibonacci number.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

> In mathematics, the Fibonacci numbers, commonly denoted `Fn`, form a sequence, called the Fibonacci sequence, such that each number is the sum of the two preceding ones, starting from `0` and `1`.

```
F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1
and 
F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2) [where n > 1]
```

**Sample Code**

```
def fib(n: int) -> int: 
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

**Output**

```
print(fib(4))
# 3
```